User requests from seperate subnet to sp2013 on prem HNSC timing out
Using 2013 enterprise. farm is 1 WFE and 1 app server.
Some of our internal users are on our network but on a different subnet and are not able to get to our hostname site collections. Others on a different VDI are able to. We (Cisco techs) confirmed that traffic is getting to the Web Front End server, and the server is just not sending replies. So, 100% not the firewall, the tunnel is working properly and the firewall isn't stopping any traffic.
The error that is displayed is an ambiguous ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
This is happening on both our production and our QA farm. Anyone experience this and find a solution?
